# optional DateType field with symfony forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony-forms, symfony

I am trying to make an user profile edition form in my Symfony 3 project.

In this attempt, I've written the following code :

The controller :

```
/**
 * @Route("/profile/edit", name="user_edit_profile", methods={"GET"})
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function editMyProfileAction($form = null) {
    return $this->render('user/edit_profile.html.twig', [
        'form' => ($form !== null) ? $form->createView() : $this->createForm(UserProfileType::class, $this->getUser())->createView()
    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/profile/edit", name="user_update_profile", methods={"POST"})
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")
 * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function updateMyProfileAction(Request $request) {
    $user = $this->getUser();

    $form = $this->createForm(UserProfileType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if(!$form->isValid()) {
        return $this->forward('AppBundle:User:editMyProfile', [
            'form' => $form
        ]);
    }
    $this->get('medievistes.user_manager')->updateUser($user);
    return $this->redirectToRoute('user_profile');
}
```

The UserType, used for registration :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\{AbstractType, FormBuilderInterface};
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\{EmailType, TextType, RepeatedType, PasswordType};

class UserType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username', TextType::class)
            ->add('email', EmailType::class)
            ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'invalid_message' => 'users.registration.password_mismatch',
                'first_options'  => ['label' => 'Password'],
                'second_options' => ['label' => 'Repeat Password'],
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
         $resolver->setDefaults(array(
             'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User'
         ));
    }
}
```

Then the UserProfileType, used for user edition :

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\{AbstractType, FormBuilderInterface};
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\{
    EmailType,
    TextType,
    RepeatedType,
    PasswordType,
    DateType
};

class UserProfileType extends UserType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        $builder
            ->add('username', TextType::class, [
                'disabled' => true
            ])
            ->add('email', TextType::class, [
                'disabled' => true
            ])
            ->add('firstname', TextType::class)
            ->add('lastname', TextType::class)
            ->add('birthdate', DateType::class, [
                'placeholder' => '',
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'required' => false,
                'inherit_data' => true,
                'empty_data' => null
            ])
            ->add('avatar', AvatarType::class)
            ->remove('plainPassword')
        ;
    }
}
```

My Doctrine field $birthdate is nullable, and I haven't set any validation constraints yet. As you can see I tried a lot of options for the "birthdate" field :

- If I just let the "widget" option, my form is displaying well, with a default value for birthdate. I want it to be optional, and set to null if the user does not fill it. But when I submit the form with the default value, I have the error "Expected argument of type "DateTime", "NULL" given".
- So I tried adding some options."required" set to false didn't help, same error.
- I set then "empty_data" to null. First improvement, I hadn't a Symfony exception when submitting, but a form error, saying "This value is invalid". I went in the Symfony profiler, telling me the DateTime Data Transformer couldn't handle null values, expecting string. I tried a string in "empty_values", but the filth tried to parse it. I do not want a datetime value when the user does not give it. Avoiding mental suicide I continued my quest for a working code.
- Reading the docs, I met with the unknown "inherit_data" options, originally disabled. I read a very interesting thing, telling me that this option, when enabled, avoid the use of Data Transformers. The filth would be ignored, right the thing I wanted. AND YES !! It worked ! After a little victory dance, I admired my blank birthdate data in the profile displaying. To ensure my victory, I tried to click on the "edit my form" button, leading to my form. And then, the neuronal slaughter :

`An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class AppBundle\Entity\User could not be converted to string") in form_div_layout.html.twig at line 13.``

- Bowing to so much hatred, I tried to give to that mysterious evil Form Component what it wanted. To my shame, I implemented a __toString method to my user class, returning the username. The form appeared again, I thought my pain was at an end. The validation worked with an empty value. With tears of joy, I committed and pushed my hotfix (if it wasn't in production, there wouldn't be any challenge). Happy again, I tried to fill the birthdate field. Even with a correct value, it remains empty.

I removed the __toString method, regaining my developer honor, observing before that that the returned username was used as a value attribute to the birthdate input (the real WTF). I'm really going to believe this is a framework issue. But I hope I'm wrong. I do not often use form component.

Please save my soul.

Comment: this error "Expected argument of type "DateTime", "NULL" given". can be solved by changing method definition by `setBirthday(\DateTime $birthday = null)`. revert all changes you have made and try this

Comment: Wonderful ! It did the job ! I just kept the "required" => false statement and it did the job !

Greath thanks to you, you made my day :D !